# Как решить задачу через стрим

Tags: java

Мне нужно достать из листа строку в виде двух геттеров через " - "

```
public class GildedRoseTest extends TestCase {
    private final GildedRose test = new GildedRose();
    private final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        items.add(new Item("+5 Dexterity Vest", 10, 20));
        items.add(new Item("Aged Brie", 2, 0));
        items.add(new Item("Elixir of the Mongoose", 5, 7));
        items.add(new Item("Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros", 0, 80));
        items.add(new Item("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 15, 20));
        items.add(new Item("Conjured Mana Cake", 3, 6));
    }

    public void testUpdateQualityFor5DexterityVest() {
        test.updateQuality(items);
        String actual = items.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getName().equals("+5 Dexterity Vest"))
                .reduce((s) -> s.getSellIn() + " - " + s.getQuality());
        // так не получается
        assertEquals("9 - 19", actual);         
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так. Писал тут, не проверял.

```java
public class GildedRoseTest extends TestCase {

    private final GildedRose test = new GildedRose();
    private final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        items.add(new Item("+5 Dexterity Vest", 10, 20));
        items.add(new Item("Aged Brie", 2, 0));
        items.add(new Item("Elixir of the Mongoose", 5, 7));
        items.add(new Item("Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros", 0, 80));
        items.add(new Item("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 15, 20));
        items.add(new Item("Conjured Mana Cake", 3, 6));
    }

    public void testUpdateQualityFor5DexterityVest() {
        test.updateQuality(items);
        Optional<String> actual = items.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getName().equals("+5 Dexterity Vest"))
                .map(s -> s.getSellIn() + " - " + s.getQuality())
                .findFirst();

        assertEquals("9 - 19", actual.get());         
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все пошло!!!!!!!